# gvim follow file directory

Tags: gvim

Can I get gvim to automatically change the (local) working directory to the current file directory when I change tabs.  Or at the very least is there a shortcut command for doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, put

```
set autochdir
```

in  your vimrc.

Comment: "It's only available if Vim was built with netbeans integration or Sun visual workshop integration." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708623/opening-files-in-the-same-folder-as-the-current-file-in-vim/1708991#1708991

Comment: Yes. But, if I'm not mistaken that's the default download option from vim.org.

Answer (score 0):

I htink you looking for autochdir.  It should be a builtin command in your vim. To have the current working dir always be what ever buffer you're in, add `set autochdir` to your vimrc.  This is automatic, but  may break saving & loading sessions.  Check [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_to_the_directory_of_the_current_file) out for more options.  An alternative is to add this to your vimrc:

```
autocmd BufEnter * lcd %:p:h
```

This question [has also appeared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708623/opening-files-in-the-same-folder-as-the-current-file-in-vim) on Stack Overflow